# Copying value of <p> element to clipboard using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a password generator which generates a random passwords and displays inside a `<p>` element. That part works fine.

I want to copy the output value (generated password) in the `<p>` element to the clipboard when the user clicks on the password value in `<p>`

Here's my code:

```js
function copyPassword() {

    let password = document.getElementById("pwd").innerText
    let message = document.getElementById("msg")

    //This doesn't seem to work
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(password) 

    //This works
    message.innerText = "Copied to clipboard"
}
```

```html
<p id="pwd" onclick="copyPassword()">click me</p>
<p id="msg"></p>
```

UPDATE:
I just checked in Firefox; this code seems to work perfectly. But it doesn't on Chrome, Edge and Safari.

UPDATE 2:
I uploaded the files to a GitHub repo and published. Works just fine. So no issues with the code.

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a permissions policy applied to the current document. See /* url */ for more details.` seems like an `iframe` issue here. Do you get similar error on your site?

Comment: Got this error with Ben's solution. I'm not using any iframes at all, so I don't understand the error msg.

Answer (score 0):

`writeText` is an async function, you should use `then` to get the result.

And chrome has some limitations for it, you can see error message if it failed.

```js
function copyPassword() {

    let password = document.getElementById("pwd").innerText
    let message = document.getElementById("msg")

    //This doesn't seem to work
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(password)
      .then(() => {
        //This works
        message.innerText = "Copied to clipboard"
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        message.innerText = err.message
      })

    
}
```

```html
<p id="pwd" onclick="copyPassword()">click me</p>
<p id="msg"></p>
```

Comment: Solution works in Firefox, but not in Chrome, Edge and Safari.

Getting this error in VS code:
"The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a permissions policy applied to the current document. See [link] (https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes) for more details.

Comment: I'm not using any iframes at all, so I don't understand the error msg.

Comment: @GreenGator Do you try it in your project? The stackoverflow's snippet runs in an iframe, so the API is always denied. You can copy the codes to your project then try it.

Comment: Hi Ben, I uploaded the files to a GitHub repo and published. Works just fine.